# Transfer node data to a XML file from response in Soap UI

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

If I have the following response in Soap UI:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ConvertTempResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <ConvertTempResult>40</ConvertTempResult>
      </ConvertTempResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm able to get the entire response copied to a text file using:

```
 //create folder and file. 
 createFolder = new File("C:/SOAPUI")  
 createFolder.mkdir()
 file = new File("C:/SOAPUI/test.txt")
 file.createNewFile()

 a = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Property Transfer")
 responsedata = a.getProperty('transfer')

 file.write(responsedata)
```

How do I get data for specific node copied. For example, If need '40' copied only. How   can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [XmlHolder](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/XmlHolder.html) and then apply XPath to get the node value, see the code below:

```
//create folder and file
createFolder = new File("C:/SOAPUI")  
createFolder.mkdir()
file = new File("C:/SOAPUI/test.txt")
file.createNewFile()

a = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Property Transfer")
responsedata = a.getProperty('transfer')

// create an XmlHolder
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
// get the response as string
def responseAsString = responsedata.getProperty('response').getValue()    
def xml = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseAsString)
// get the node value
def nodeValue = xml.getNodeValue("//*:ConvertTempResult")
log.info nodeValue;

file.write(nodeValue)
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I'm getting the following error by using the above code: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.getXmlHolder() is applicable for argument types: (com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep$3) values: [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep$3@781081b9] Possible solutions: getXmlHolder(java.lang.String) error at line: 11

Comment: Sorry, I supposed that your responsedata was an String with the response but it's the testStep, so you need to get the response as string before operate with XmlHolder. I update the answer with this change :).